# Git: Delete the branch only if there is no warning

Tags: git

I used the following command to delete my local branches that have been merged into `HEAD`.

```
>>> git branch | xargs git branch -d 
>>> # (not -D) because I don't wanted to forced delete all the branches
```

But I noticed that it also deleted a branch that is not merged to `HEAD` but was pushed to remote.

Warning with error: (Branch was not deleted)

> ```
> warning: not deleting branch 'ER-1421' that is not yet merged to
>          'refs/remotes/origin/ER-1421', even though it is merged to HEAD.
> error: The branch 'ER-1421' is not fully merged.
> ```

Warning without error: (It has been deleted from local)

> ```
> warning: deleting branch 'ER-2256' that has been merged to
>          'refs/remotes/origin/ER-2256', but not yet merged to HEAD.
> Deleted branch ER-2256 (was d18dafcee).
> ```

My question is: How can I restrict deleting branches that for which deletion would give **any warning** or are not merged to `HEAD`?

Update: Based on @Saurav comment. I tried with below command

```
>>>git branch --merged | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs git branch -d

warning: not deleting branch 'ER-1421' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/ER-1421', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'ER-1421' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D ER-1421'.
error: branch '*' not found.
error: Cannot delete branch 'master' checked out at '/media/sf_workspace/personify'
warning: not deleting branch 'release-66' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/release-66', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'release-66' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D release-66'.
```

Comment: Are you talking about a pre-receive hook ? You don't want to delete remote or local ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to delete only local branches which are merged to HEAD then I would rather suggest to select only those branches to delete which are fully merged to HEAD.
A small modification in your command would solve the issue:

```
git branch --merged | xargs git branch -d
```

`git branch --merged` only lists those branches which are fully merged. Then rest you can delete with `xargs git branch -d`. Also make sure you run this command from the branch where HEAD points, prabably *master* branch.

Hope it helps!